# I don't understand this piece of MySQL notation and subsequently don't know how to do it in Postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have this MySQL query, and it works on a MySQL database, but not on a PostgreSQL one:

```
select setype from _entity where id='72@78|'
```

Now, what exactly is `'72@78|'` trying to do? id is an integer field, so when the query is run on a Postgressql DB, it gives an `invalid input syntax for integer: "72@78|"` error.

I know that `|` is a bitwise OR operator, but what exactly is being ORED here? And, just as importantly, what is the `@` for? I tried to look for it in the MySQL manual, but due to sub-par searching skills, I couldn't find it.

When I run the above query on a MySQL DB, it finds data with an id value of `72`,somehow, the expression evaluates to the first number.

So, what is the above query trying to do, and how do I convert it into a PostgreSQL equivalent?

Thanks for all your help, have a good day.

Comment: It's a string. An odd one, but a string nonetheless. Nothing inside of a string, except a `'` would be interpreted by the DB server. The syntax error you're getting is a natural consequence of trying to stuff a string into an integer context. MySQL is being polite and simply extracting the first integer it could find in the string (72), while postgres is being more picky.

Comment: Do you have control over the code that is trying to use that string in the query or do you have to fix it in the SQL itself?

Comment: @MarcB Oh, it's just a string, wow, silly of me not to realize that. I guess MySQL is quite a bit more polite when it comes to error checking and stuff.

Comment: @muistooshort I have control over the code that is generating the string. I am trying to figure out exactly where it is generated, and see if I can cut it early. If I can't do that, then I would have to write some php that can strip away everything after the `@`, I am not 100% sure on how to do that though.

Comment: *Polite* isn't the word I'd use for it :) You'll want to check all your GROUP BYs (MySQL will guess when there is ambiguity, PostgreSQL will not) and all your INSERTs and UPDATEs (MySQL will silently truncate your data, PostgreSQL will complain).

Comment: You'll want to convert that string to an integer inside PHP *and* remove the quotes in the query, `'11'` is still a string as far as PostgreSQL is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is converting the text string to a numeric, and ignoring anything after the first non-numeric character, therefore, it is just comparing `id = 72`, which is what you are getting from the output.

My guess is that PostgreSQL is trying to convert the whole string to an integer and failing because it isn't a valid integer value.

To do the equivalent in PostgreSQL, you would need to convert the `72@78|` to a simple integer before running your query.

Comment: Yup, that's the problem. The query runs fine if I just change it to `72`. Now, I need to fix the php that generates the string, hmm.

Comment: Indeed, and that may have to be your next question to the StackOverflow collective :)